# Combine ODE with constraints using a Lagrange multiplier

Tags: algebraic-equations

Consider a constrained ODE system:
\begin{align}
\dot{\bf x} &= \bf f(t,\bf x), \\ 
st. 0 &= \bf g(t,\bf x).
\end{align}
I wish to combine these into a single equation using a Lagrange multiplier, however I am unsure how to do it. I talked with my supervisor the other day about it and he quickly scribbled the following down:
\begin{equation}
\dot{\bf x} + (\nabla_\bf x \bf g(\bf x))^\top \lambda = \bf f(t,\bf x).
\end{equation}
However, it was a last moment thing so it might not be entirely correct, and I don't really see how he would get that. But then again I don't exactly see how I can apply the Lagrange method in the first place since it requires a function you wish to maximize/minimize, whereas I have $\bf f(t,\bf x) - \dot{\bf x} = 0$.

Does anyone have any advice on how to approach this problem?

### Based on the information Carlo Beenakker gave me I have attempted the following:

I tried following the method outlined in: https://ep.liu.se/ecp/084/010/ecp13084010.pdf section 6.

If I understand this correctly I want to turn my constrained ODE into an optimization under constraint problem, which leads to a lagrangian equation.

So I consider equation (63-64):
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}({\bf x}) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} L(t,{\bf x}, {\bf \dot{x}}) dt
\end{equation}
subject to the constraints
\begin{equation}
\phi({\bf x}) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} h(t,{\bf x}) dt = 0
\end{equation}

I can see that the first equation is similar to my original equation with ${\bf f}(t,{\bf x}) = L(t,{\bf x}, \bf \dot{x})$, and the constraints I guess are related as such:
\begin{equation}
h(t,{\bf x}) = \frac{d}{dt} g(t,{\bf x})
\end{equation}

This then leads me to equation 67:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf x}} - \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf \dot{x}}} \right) = \nabla_{\bf x} h({\bf x}) \lambda
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
However, if I use ${\bf f}(t,{\bf x}) = L(t,{\bf x}, \bf \dot{x})$, and insert it, I get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(t,{\bf x})}{\partial {\bf x}} - \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial {\bf \dot{x}}}{\partial {\bf \dot{x}}} \right) = \frac{\partial f(t,{\bf x})}{\partial {\bf x}} = \nabla_{\bf x} h({\bf x}) \lambda
\end{equation}
***Which doesn't look right. So I'm guessing I did something wrong or there is something I have forgotten. Anyone that can give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong?***

Comment: You have what is known as a [Differential-algebraic system of equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential-algebraic_system_of_equations). This can be reduced to a system of ODE's using Lagrange multipliers, as explained for example in [Simplification of Differential Algebraic Equations by the Projection Method](https://ep.liu.se/ecp/084/010/ecp13084010.pdf).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker , Thank you for the information and paper! I tried to follow the method outlined in the paper you linked, but I'm pretty sure I have done something wrong, since the final result doesn't look right.